# When you create a class in Java, what is the class implicitly extending?

Tags: java, inheritance

When I create a class in Java, like...

```
public class Card
{
}
```

what is this class implicitly extending? Is it only extending an Object or is it also extending some other classes?

Comment: base Object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes that are made that include no `extend` element only extend the Object class.